# adding hidden layer drastically decreasing performance of neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have some code for a single layer neural network:

```
class network {

var outputs;
var weights;
var biases;

feedforward(inputs) {
}

outputFunction(number) {
}

}
```

The output function is a sigmoid (so returns a number between 0 and 1). The inputs are an array of 1s and 0s.

I added a hidden layer by adding outputs2, weights2, biases2, and then doing:

```
feedforward2(inputs) {
    use weights2, biases2, etc.
}

feedforwad(inputs) {
   inputs = feedforward2(inputs)
   ....
}
```

I figured that the inputs of the output nodes are now the outputs of my hidden layer, so it should at least have similar performance. Yet, performance has drastically reduced after training the network again. Any ideas? Training does not have backpropagation to the hidden layer yet, it just updates the weights of the output layer and the hidden layer weights stay the same always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hidden layer weights are random and fixed, then all they do is distort the signal.

Training multilayer networks is difficult. The vast majority of them has only a single hidden layer, with the exceptions of convolutional networks and some recent work on deep belief networks.